# Diagonalizability as a measure of uncertainty (discrete case)

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I have seen two characterizations of the problem in measuring a discrete variable of a state ψ exactly with each of two non-commuting Hermitian operators A and B:

(1) that the product of the standard deviations ( = √(<ψ|A2|ψ>-<ψ|A|ψ>2), & ditto for B) ≥ 1

(2) that one cannot simultaneously diagonalize the matrix representations of A and B
(i.e., if A = U†CU and B = V†DV, for unitary U and V and diagonal C and D, with † denoting the adjoint, then U≠V.

Where is the link between these two?

Comment: I'm almost sure this is a duplicate of some question on the site but I can't seem to find it at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a situation where $[A,B] = iC$, and $\omega$ is any state of the C*-algebra containing $A,B,C$, then you have the relation
$$\Delta_\omega A\Delta_\omega B\geq \frac12|\omega(C)|$$
which is an answer to your first question, provided that, e.g., $[A,B] = i2\cdot\mathbf 1$.

Part two is basically the fact that, unless $A$ and $B$ commute, their product is not self-adjoint, and therefore it won't diagonalise. This violates the fact that, if they were diagonalisable, then their product would be diagonal.

Comment: There were not two questions, but one question about the link between the two principles: Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle  (in which I should have put |<s|[A,B]|s>|/2) and the matrix form complementarity. In the meantime, apparently the link is that there is a fourier transform between the two bases, and a non-zero function and its fourier transform cannot both be sharply localized. (source: Wiki) I will have to delve into wave harmonics to better understand this, however.